# How to have same URL for home feed but also for login page if user is not logged in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

So I am working on a PERN stack app (postgresql, expressjs, reactjs, nodejs).

And I was wondering... How does facebook or instagram code the thing where, If I am logged in, the url: [www.instagram.com](http://www.instagram.com) shows my feed, but if I am not logged in, [www.instagram.com](http://www.instagram.com) shows the login page (without changing the url to something like instagram.com/login or similar...)

So my question is, how do they do this?

I have tried looking into solutions with react router, and couldn't find any :/...

I think this could be done by changing the state of the app but thats not how I would like to resolve the routing on my app.. (it's a social media kind of app)

Comment: Can you show us in code, what have you tried and what's not working?

Comment: Problem is, I did not try to code this because I have no idea how this can be done :/
I hoped that somebody already encountered this way of routing and could help me do the same

Comment: The problem is - if you don't give specifics then all we can provide is only general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general logical flow, I would suggest the following:

1. Define a home route i.e the app base url (/) such that it's a common route for both authorized and non-authorized pages. This should also be the root route component in the react-router.
2. Check user session/authentication in the home route as the first step:

   - If the user is authenticated, render authorized components and sub-routes eg: /profile, /account, etc.
   - Else, render public components which is usually the login/signup pages.
3. On logout, redirect the user back to home route (/).

This is a very high-level flow which is usually pretty much the same regardless of the stack you use.

Comment: Thank you! I found that this can be done with react router ProtectedRoutes